# No me deja ingresar un dato Boolean

Tags: mysql

Sucede que cuando ingreso en el MySql WorkBeanch el atributo **`BOOLEAN`** me lo transforma en in `tinyint`...

Sera lo mismo o es diferente al boolean?

Comment: En la [documentacion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html) se observa que el el rango de valores de tinyint va desde -128 a 128 en cambio un Boolean el valor es 0-1 o null salvo que declares [tinyint(1)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) seria casi igual

Comment: Entonces sin importar cual utilice se pude utilizar como si fueran lo mismo?

Comment: no es lo mismo, en cuanto a peso en base de datos

Comment: A listo muchas gracias :3

Comment: me equioque si son sinonimos esta en el enlace de tinyint(1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En la [Documentacion Oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) nos dice que :

> These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered
>   false. Nonzero values are considered true

la Traducción:

> El TINYINT(1) es la representación de boolean. Donde un 0 es
>   considerado Falso y cualquier otro valor es considerado como  TRUE.

Answer (score 3):

En mysql, el tipo de dato tinyint(1) es sinónimo de boolean. Un valor 0 se considera falso. Cualquier otro valor, verdadero.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

el tinyint te puede regresar dos valores:

- El número 0, que sería igual a false.
- El número 1, que sería igual a true.

estos números representarían al dato tipo boolean.